# Hiding Rows Based on linked cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am brand new to VBA but I'm trying to accomplish the following task in Excel.
I have cells `B3:B192` on sheet2 linked to `D3:D192` on sheet1. On sheet2 any row that doesn't have a value in column B to be hidden. I've been looking around at some of the questions others have asked regarding similar problems but I can't seem to make anything work for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you show the work you've done to try to accomplish this yourself and provide an [mcve] we can help you a lot more. For more understanding, see [why is "please help" not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Data Filter isn't an option?